# Laravel Echo + pusher, stop trying to connect to server if server is not available

Tags: laravel-echo, pusher-js

How to stop trying to create a connection when getting a server connection fail?

```
const echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wssHost: window.location.hostname,
    wssPort: 6001,
    encrypted: true,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['wss'],
})
```